# Multisite pagination with get_posts

Tags: multisite, pagination, get-posts

I'm looking for a way to paginate my get_posts :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
                    'offset'           => 0,
                    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
                    'order'            => 'DESC',
                    'post_type'        => 'post',
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'suppress_filters' => true,
                    'paged'            => $paged,
                    ); 

                $query = get_posts($args);
```

I've been trying to get this on my own but I did not succeed. Here is my paginate function :

```
function my_pagination($query = false){
global $wp_query;

if ( !$query ) $query = $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'         => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
        'type'         => 'list',
        'prev_text'    => __('%s Previous','textdomain'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next %s','textdomain'),
    ) );
}
```

I call it in my template with :

```
if ( function_exists('my_pagination') ) my_pagination($query);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: RESOLVED BY MYSELF

Comment: If you post your solution as an answer and accept it, then others in the same situation can see a *solved* question.

Comment: You should be able to.  (There might be a waiting period, though...)

Comment: ok ^^ I'll do it ASAP.

Comment: Looks like it's a [48-hour waiting period](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to that was pretty simple. I just replaced `get_posts()` with a simple new `WP_query()` :

```
$query = new WP_query($args);
```

I guess now you have a ready-to-implement function for pagination ^^